# Weird django admin importerror

Tags: python, django, exception, importerror

I am getting a weird import error when I try to access admin: http://dpaste.com/292489/ It doesn't seem to be related to my code and I have setup all the proper admin settings and urls, since admin has worked properly before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I think to do is to double check your PYTHONPATH and triple check that your ROOT_URLCONF is pointing to the right spot.